# Instantiate GameObject at gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I wondered how you can instantiate Public GameObject on another Public Transform?

And if I want to instantiate on `GUI.Button` press, do I do

```
If(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2 + 100, 100, 25), "Test"))
{
    Instantiate(mag, transform.position, transform.rotation)
}
```

Here is my script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Gun;

    public Transform magTransform;
    public GameObject mag;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
        {
            Instantiate(mag, transform.magTransform, transform.rotation);
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2 + 100, 100, 25), "Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wondered how you can insantiate Public GameObject on another Public
>   Transform

I assume that `magTransform` is that other transform. To instantiate your `mag` prefab on the location of the `magTransform` Transform, just use `magTransform.position` and `magTransform.rotation`.

Simply change

```
Instantiate(mag, transform.magTransform, transform.rotation);
```

to

```
Instantiate(mag, magTransform.position, magTransform.rotation);
```

---

> And if i want to instantiate on GUI.Button press

Do not use the `GUI.XXX` API or anything that needs to be placed in the `OnGUI` function. Exception to this is when you are making an editor plugin. Use the new UI system then register to a UI Button event to get notified when it is clicked on. You can find simple official tutorial for the UI system on Unity's [website](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui).

With the correct UI system, your code should look like something below:

```
public GameObject Gun;

public Transform magTransform;
public GameObject mag;


public Button instantiateButton;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    instantiateButton.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(instantiateButton));
}

private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
{
    if (buttonPressed == instantiateButton)
    {
        //Your code for Instantiate button 
        Instantiate(mag, magTransform.position, magTransform.rotation);
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Events
    instantiateButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot!